# Subtracting each node of two integer stacks

Tags: java, math, stack

I have been trying to write a little program that calculates extremely large integers, ones that the BigInteger class cannot handle in Java. My approach was to make the Integer a string and push it onto a stack and then compare both stack's `pop()` and do math, and `push()` the outcome. This approach worked for my adding, a addStacks method that takes two Stacks as a parameter. This works great as far as I've tested adding large numbers.

```
 int carry = 0;

            while(!stackA.empty() && !stackB.empty())
            {
                try
                {   
                    //get the digits to add
                    int tokenA = stackA.pop();
                    int tokenB = stackB.pop();

                    //add them and mod 10
                    int result = tokenA + tokenB + carry;
                    int resultDigit = result % 10;

                    //push the result on to the new stack
                    resultStack.push(resultDigit);

                    //the updated carry
                    carry = result / 10;
                }
                catch(ArithmeticException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (carry > 0)
            {
                resultStack.push(carry);
            }
```

My Problem is when i try to implement the same logic with subtraction. In my mind i assumed both operations would be alike. My subtraction method, the only real difference between the two methods is additional code to ensure that the larger number is always subtracting a smaller number. I feel my approach is off, as when i enter the `100` and `10` i get the result `010` haha which is very wrong as it should be `90`. Any tips on how to fix my math here?

```
int carry = 0;

        while (!stackA.empty() && !stackB.empty())
        {
            int tempA = 0;    
            int tempB = 0;

            int tokenA = stackA.pop();
            int tokenB = stackB.pop();

            if (tokenA <= tokenB)
            {
                tempA = tokenB;
                tempB = tokenA;

                //System.out.println("StackApop: " + tokenA);
                //System.out.println("StackBpop: " + tokenB);

                int result = tempA - tempB;
                int resultDigit = result % 10;

                resultStack.push(resultDigit);

                carry = result / 10;
            }
            else if (tokenA >= tokenB)
            {
                int result = tempA - tempB;
                int resultDigit = result % 10;

                resultStack.push(resultDigit);

                carry = result / 10;
            }
        }
        if (carry > 0)
        {
            resultStack.push(carry);
        }
```

Comment: Quiz question: what is the biggest number java's `BigInteger` can handle?

Comment: @NándorElődFekete: BigIntegers seem to be limited by its byte array constructor and toByteArray method to at most Integer.MAX_INT bytes, or 2^31 - 1 bytes (in practice actually a little less). Internally, the implementations may be able to generate larger numbers, but they'd have no way of getting them out. So the largest number would be about 256^2147483647, where "^" means exponentiation, not XOR.

Comment: @JamesKPolk yes, my quiz question was a subtle way to make the question poster think about whether he really needs to make a custom implementation, because an integer of 2Gbytes worth of bits is still quite a big number.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete: Oh, sorry. But anyway, Strings and stacks have the same limitations so you can't get bigger ints via them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rename carry into borrow.

```
            int result = tempA - tempB - carry;
            carry = result < 0 ? 1 : 0;
            result += 10*carry;
            int resultDigit = result % 10;

            resultStack.push(resultDigit);


    if (carry > 0)
    {
        resultStack.push(10 - carry); // Negative number actually
    }
```

BigInteger is quite clever, you might want to look in the sources.

---

When subtracting two digits, it might be that one digit already in the prior step was decreased by one, to add 10 in the prior step.

When subtracting and getting a negative result, add ten, and let 1 be subtracted from the following step.

(Using modulo `%` requires paying attention to negative numbers; the outcome may be negative.)

Comment: I know that the BigInteger class would be helpful, Its not that it doesn't fit what i am trying to do, i am just intentionally trying to do it without using that java class. Could you explain a little of the code here? I've tried implementing it and am getting closer.

Comment: Added the explanation, and I understand the desire - despite the existence of BigInteger - to try doing it oneself once. But other visitors should be pointed to BigInteger.